# Knockout JS - Why do all the examples only contain ViewModel/View but no Model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am looking through alot of the Knockout JS documentation available, however it doesn't seem to follow the MVVM pattern as I would expect (when looking at Wikipedia's definition of MVVM).

In all the examples they seem to show source code for ViewModels and Views however there is never a model, now it seems like most of the functionality that the model should contain (saving/retrieving a representation of data) is put within the ViewModel. I thought that maybe the ViewModels were actually more akin to the Model, and the binding layer that you kinda get for free is the ViewModel, as that does all the bindings...

So I am just wondering if I am missing something here? As I have a question open at the moment about where my UI logic should go, i.e adding Watermarks, Inter-View chatter etc and I haven't really got a solid answer for it, so wanted to confirm that my understanding of the pattern usage within this framework is correct before continuing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Web development, the Views and ViewModel are at the client-side.

The Models are at the server side.

The models represent the real objects while the View Models only represent them in terms of the view in which they are displayed e.g. in Customer Model you have all the information related to the Customer but in a Customer View Model you might only have Customer Name (because that's all your showing on the view).

Most of the knockoutjs example don't explain the Model bit is because it is server-side dependent and could be written in Ruby/C#/Python etc. Knockout only deals with the View Model and View; It's server side agnostic.

The server side tech is required to develop the Model layer in MVVM. Knockoutjs is required to develop the VM-V layer.

Comment: That makes sense I guess, so like with domain driven development, you have 2 models on each domain, the model (server - my web service) and the view model (client - knockout js). However that still leaves me a bit baffled as to where view related functionality should reside... if I should introduce a controller which deals with binding the viewmodel to the view, and assigning any functionality to the view, as I want to keep my viewmodel only concerned with data, and my view only concerned with display... that leaves a void for anything else :(

Comment: all my UI logic goes into the ViewModel class (or inside the view templates if they are pretty simple). I am not too sure how testable they are but I can't think of any other place to put them. If the UI logic is only required at server-side then it goes into the controller.

Comment: I am talking about a clientside controller, I currently have ALOT of client side code that needs testing, which also uses a dependency injector of sorts. If it is wrapped within a controller it is testable and also doesn't blur the concerns of any of the layers. As the viewmodel is still only concerned with being a well defined repository of sorts, and the view only worries about giving a front end to the view. I dont really like in-line javascript (which is the only other option outside of putting it in viewmodel).

Comment: sorry if I am not getting you, but client-side viewmodel is not only for data but it should contain all the UI logic too. At least that's my point of view. It is responsible for anything and everything happening at the UI. This point of view IMO is also enhance how knockout works i.e build your viewmodel with everything you need and then bind it. If you can show us an example code which you are not sure where to add that'll help (do that in your original question).

Comment: The project I am porting over is too large to post anything worthwhile down. The thing that I find a bit hard to get my head around is that in my eyes the ViewModel should only be concerned with exposing the data to the view, acting as a binding layer really, however if I start putting other logic in there it becomes more than that and ends up being large and hard to understand. Maybe I need to look at it another way and do it through composition, so I will just put all other functionality into their own classes and delegate through from the ViewModel.